# How to call a property combined with a variable?

Tags: php, variables, properties

In my class I have 2 properties called:

- private $sender_host
- private $receiver_host

My method gives a parameter called '$target' and this can only be the string 'sender' or 'receiver'.

I now would like to call the right property, depending what the parameter $target says. This is the way I want it to be called: `$this->$parameter . '_host'` ... that means, when $target equals 'sender', it should return the value of the property $sender_host and when it equals 'receiver', it should return the value of $receiver_host but I guess the way I am trying it won't work. So is there another way I could reach my goal?

Comment: Show real code efforts, vague description is no substitute for a concrete code example

Comment: `return $this->{$parameter . '_host'}` perhaps, at a guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply by `$this->{$target . '_host'}` (yes, I think you mentioned `$target` at first)

Comment: Oh I didn't know about the using of those curly braces but that helped! Thank you!